# QWebView Open in new Window

Tags: qt, webkit, qwebview

I want to open links from a `QWebView` with `target="_blank"` in a new window of a new process.

I tried using `QWebView::createWindow(QWebPage::WebWindowType)`, but I didn't find a way to get the url to send to the new process. Actually, I tried a hack to get the url using a hidden `QWebView` (returned by the `createWindow` method) with the `urlChanged` event, but sometimes this event is triggered twice, so it is not reliable.

Is there any way to get the URL in the `createWindow` method?

If not, what can I do to open this kind of links in a new window of a new process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do what I want.

I had to overload the `mousePressEvent` to get the mouse position so that I can get the url from it.

Here is the code:

```
QWebView* WebView::createWindow(QWebPage::WebWindowType) {
    QWebHitTestResult result{page()->mainFrame()->hitTestContent(lastClickPosition)};
    openNewWindow(result.linkUrl());
    return nullptr;
}

void WebView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* mouseEvent) {
    lastClickPosition = mouseEvent->pos();
    QWebView::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

I let this question opened a few days to see if anyone can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying for a multi-process webview architecture, I would suggest looking at `QtWebEngine`. `QtWebEngine` will be replacing `QtWebKit` and is based on Chromium. Because of this, it has a multi-process architecture by default. `QtWebEngine` will no longer be updated, so I would suggest migrating to `QtWebEngine` anyway.

[QtWebEngine overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html)

Comment: I think Qt Webkit is also multi-process (since Webkit 2), but I really want to be able to open an URL in a new process (launched explicitly by my program).